# Firebase Realtime Database Emulator IP binding

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

It seems that the new emulators with firebase-tools ignore the -o --host option and always bind to localhost:9000 or 8080 (for firestore). Am I missing a new config/setting where host or port can be set for the emulators?

Comment: Add the exact command line you're entering to your question.

Comment: firebase serve --only database --host 192.168.4.171
+  database: started on http://localhost:9000
12:35:03.411 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started

12:35:03.573 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening on port 9000

Comment: Wait, are you on a Mac? If you are, go to terminal and enter `cat ~/.config/configstore/\@google-cloud/functions-emulator/config.json`, what is the bind host?

Comment: I'm looking in firebase-tools\lib\emulator\constants.js and while port is defined there, no options for host and firebase-tools\lib\serve\javaEmulator.js actually has localhost hardcoded in the logger: utils.logLabeledSuccess(emulator.name, "started on http://localhost:" + emulator.port); I'm wondering if its hard coded in the emulator jar

Comment: There should be a `config.json` in which you can change the `bindHost`

Comment: I didn't have \@google-cloud/functions-emulator/config.json so, i installed the npm and ran it to create the config.json - changed the bindhost and nothing changed. Perhaps a difference in the functions emulator vs database emulator?